# scan a line with numbers and words and just keep the words in c

Tags: c, file-io, scanf, text-files, fgets

I have a text file that has listed albums and songs. 
eg:
 
Pink Floyd : Dark Side of the Moon
 
0:01:30 - Speak to Me
 
0:02:43 - Breathe 
 
0:03:36 - On the Run
 
0:04:36 - The Great Gig in the Sky

I am using sscanf to get the duration of each song. When I am trying to get the name of the song im just getting a blank page. How can I just discard all the other characters I don't want. So far for the duration I use this:

```
int temp1,temp2,temp3;
char str[100];
char symbol[2]="-";

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("albums.txt","r");

if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("Error: unable to open ‘albums.txt’Report error.in mode ’r’\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}  


while (fgets(str, 100, fp) != NULL)
{
    if(strstr(str,symbol))
    {  
        sscanf(str,"%d:%d:%d",&temp1,&temp2,&temp3);
        getHour(temp1,temp2,temp3);         //temp1:hours, temp2:minutes, temp3:seconds
    }
}  

fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test the return value of `sscanf()` for success.  Use `"%*d"` to scan an `int`, yet not save.  Use `"%[^\n]"` to scan and save all non-`'\n'` characters.

Code can consume the ''-'` as part of the scan.

```
while (fgets(str, sizeof str, fp) != NULL) {
  char title[sizeof str];  // Wide enough for anything from `str`.
  if (sscanf(str, "%*d :%*d :%*d - %[^\n]", title) == 1) {
    // success
    printf("<%s>\n", title);
  }
}
```